# How to map a List of items 'n' times, but loop back to the beginning each time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm fairly new to React, so there is probably just an easier way to do this.

But I have a List of items

```
const NOTES = [
  { id: 0, val: "C" },
  { id: 1, val: "C#" },
  { id: 2, val: "D" },
  { id: 3, val: "D#" },
  { id: 4, val: "E" },
  { id: 5, val: "F" },
  { id: 6, val: "F#" },
  { id: 7, val: "G" },
  { id: 8, val: "G#" },
  { id: 9, val: "A" },
  { id: 10, val: "A#" },
  { id: 11, val: "B" },
];
```

The requirement is that a user will give a number of notes to display.
So for example, if the user gives 14 you would display

```
C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#, A, A#, B, C, C#
```

I currently have this

```
  const keys = [...Array(13).keys()];
  console.log("keys: ", keys);
  return (
    <div>
      {keys.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>{NOTES[item].val}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

But because there are only 12 elements in the List, I get an error. Is there any way to make it so that when it reaches the last element in the List, I go back to the first element and continue 'n' times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using keys.map

You can create a function

This function will receive a parameter (the number of times that you need notes in this example 14)

Then inside the func declare the NOTES array

Set a counter in 0 (let variable)

Set an empty array that you are going to fill with info after

Define a for loop that is going from 0 to the param that you defined

Inside for do an array.push
Example: myArray.push(NOTES[counter])

Execute counter++
If the counter is 11 set it to 0 again

Then outside for loop return the array

Then replace keys.map with myFunc(16).map

And each item will be the array that are you looking for

Hope this helps you to find the right solution

Comment: I tried this in the past, but I didn't think it worked because I didn't know at the time that you need to specify the array type

So after setting the type, I got this working perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: I like the flowchart approach instead of a definitive code solution.  "Then replace keys.map ..."  - nice touch. However I'd add "test ..." immediately before "... replace ..." +1

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is stupid like me, Jurgen's solution is the way to go.

I got errors in the past due to now giving a type for my array.

```
  var arr: string[] = [];
```

So the full solution would be something like this

```
var arr: string[] = [];
  var c = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < numFrets; i++) {
    arr[i] = NOTES[c].val;
    c++;
    if (c == 12) {
      c = 0;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map((item) => (
        <div>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modulo](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/modulo.htm#:%7E:text=Modulo%20is%20a%20math%20operation,and%20r%20is%20the%20remainder.) to loop back to the start of the array:

```js
const NOTES = [{
    id: 0,
    val: "C"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    val: "C#"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    val: "D"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    val: "D#"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    val: "E"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    val: "F"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    val: "F#"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    val: "G"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    val: "G#"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    val: "A"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    val: "A#"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    val: "B"
  }
];

function getNoteSequence(numOfNotes) {
  numOfNotes = numOfNotes || 0;

  const totalNotesDefined = NOTES.length;

  const result = [];
  for (let currNote = 0; currNote < numOfNotes; currNote++) {
    result.push(NOTES[currNote % totalNotesDefined]);
  }

  return result;
}

function generateHTML() {
  const noteSequence = getNoteSequence(14);

  document
    .querySelector('#notes-container')
    .innerHTML = noteSequence
      .map((note) => `<div key="${ note.id }">${ note.val }</div>`)
      .join('');
}

generateHTML();
```

```html
<div id="notes-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As jurgen has already mentioned, the same thing has been done below:

```
const NOTES = [
  { id: 0, val: "C" },
  { id: 1, val: "C#" },
  { id: 2, val: "D" },
  { id: 3, val: "D#" },
  { id: 4, val: "E" },
  { id: 5, val: "F" },
  { id: 6, val: "F#" },
  { id: 7, val: "G" },
  { id: 8, val: "G#" },
  { id: 9, val: "A" },
  { id: 10, val: "A#" },
  { id: 11, val: "B" },
];


const userInput = 14;
const keys = [...Array(13).keys()];
console.log("keys: ", keys);


const prepareFinalList = () => {
  const finalListEl = [];
  let userInputCounter = 0;
  let i = 0;

// this userInput variable required to break the loop
  while(userInputCounter <= userInput) {
    if (i > NOTES.length - 1) {
      i = 0;
    }

    const item = NOTES[i];

    finalListEl[userInputCounter] = (<div key={item.id}>{item.val}</div>)
    
    i++;
    userInputCounter++;
  }

  // this will have the mapped dom structure
  return finalListEl;
};


return (
  <div>
    {/* 
    1. instead of using map you should use different loop. Maybe normal for loop or while loop 
       and prepared your own Dom's array.

    */}
    {prepareFinalList()}
  </div>
);
```